# Problem with the logout on Rails API + Devise + JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, jwt, devise-jwt

Im building a Rails API. All my devise routes working fine, execpt for one : the **logout**.

I followed this tutorial : https://jameschambers.co.uk/rails-api

I already tried few things, like :

- tried the api/logout.json route
- tried to change rb #111 for : config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :params_auth] ( config/initializers/devise.rb )
- tried to change rb #280 for : config.sign_out_via = :get ( config/initializers/devise.rb )

Im sending a DELETE request on this address : localhost:3000/api/logout, with a JWT/Bearer token.

**error**

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column jwt_denylist.exp does not exist\nLINE 1: ...jwt_denylist\" WHERE \"jwt_denylist\".\"jti\" = $1 AND \"jwt_denyl...
```

**rails routes**

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /api/logout(.:format)                                                                             sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_09_01_233823) do


  create_table "jwt_denylist", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "jti", null: false
    t.datetime "expired_at", null: false
    t.index ["jti"], name: "index_jwt_denylist_on_jti"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private

  def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    render_jsonapi_response(resource)
  end

  def respond_to_on_destroy
    head :no_content
  end

end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist

end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options :host => "http://localhost:3000"
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :users, only: %w[show]
  end

  devise_for :users,
    defaults: { format: :json },
    path: '',
    path_names: {
      sign_in: 'api/login',
      sign_out: 'api/logout',
      registration: 'api/signup'
    },
    controllers: {
      sessions: 'sessions',
      registrations: 'registrations'
    }
  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `ERROR:  column jwt_denylist.exp does not exist` indicates it's looking for a column (`exp`) that doesn't exist on the `jwt_denylist` table.

Your schema shows you have an `expired_at` but no `exp` column.

From the [jwt-denylist](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) gem the schema it expects `exp`. Perhaps the tutorial is out of date? Here's what the gem's documentation recommends:

```rb
  create_table :jwt_denylist do |t|
    t.string :jti, null: false
    t.datetime :exp, null: false
  end
  add_index :jwt_denylist, :jti
```

So i would rename the `:expired_at` column to `:exp`, e.g.

`rails generate migration rename_expired_at_to_exp_on_jwt_denylist` and make the change method something like:

```rb
def change
  rename_column :jwt_denylist, :expired_at, :exp
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, thanks Melcher !! :)

This is what the migration looked like

```
class CreateJwtDenylist < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :jwt_denylist do |t|
      t.string :jti, null: false
      t.datetime :expired_at, null: false
    end
    add_index :jwt_denylist, :jti
  end
end
```

This is what is looks like now

```
class CreateJwtDenylist < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :jwt_denylist do |t|
      t.string :jti, null: false
      t.datetime :exp, null: false
    end
    add_index :jwt_denylist, :jti
  end
end
```